# Why do you say this way?

Tags: grammar

There is a situation in an english teaching video:

A and B are friends. They haven't seen each other in a long time. Now A sees B at a pub.

> A: How long is it? Three years ...

I wonder why A doesn't say "how long has it been?" instead?

Comment: I agree with you Vova.  "How long is it?" requests physical distance or time _over_ a specific event such as, "How long is the film?".  "How long has it been?" requests elapsed time _between_ events.  In my experience you do not switch them and expect them to be understood in the opposite context.

Comment: **How long is it...?** is a typical colloquial way of asking **How long has it been (since we met)?** Do not expect people to converse in grammatically correct English.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's technically grammatically incorrect, but it's idiomatic, and sounds natural.

"How long has it *been*?" (with the emphasis on the last word) is more emphatic, but unless that's what you want to say (that is: "it has been an *extremely* long time), it would be more common for someone to say "How long is it?"

Comment: Why did this get downvoted? Feel like explaining?

Comment: not a downvoter, but "How long is it?" is not "technically grammatically incorrect"

Comment: @JamesK It's not incorrect if you're talking about an item which has a length that can be measured. A period of time should indeed technically be described as having been in the past, so can't be "is".